# Zingchart click event handling

Tags: charts, zingchart

I am not sure where to put following zingchart click event handling code in the html page.
zingchart.click = function(dataStr){
    var data = eval('(' + dataStr + ')');
    alert("Chart Clicked - ID: " + data["id"]);
}

If anybody knows please provide the sample HTML code.

Answer (score 3):

The `zingchart.click` function can go anywhere after the zingchart script include.

Here is an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../zingchart-1.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div id="zingchart"></div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var jsonConfig = '{"graphset" : [{"type" : "line","series" : [{"values" : [5, 10, 15, 5, 10, 5]}] }]}';

        zingchart.render({
            data            : jsonConfig,
            width           : 600,
            height          : 300,
            container       : 'zingchart'
        });

        zingchart.click = function(data){ 
            alert("Chart Clicked - ID: " + data["id"]); 
       }
        </script>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```